# PHP Function to shorten string to exactly 3 characters

Tags: php

The fact that I don't know how to do this is a good example of how elementary my PHP skills are.

How can I shorten a string `$fr_month` to 3 characters as a function"`short_fr_month()`"?

Comment: FYI, generally languages that have some sort of string handling,implement some sort of `substring` functionality, often abbreviated as `substr`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$fr_month = substr($fr_month,0,3);
```

The "0,3" means an offset of 0 characters, and a length of 3.

Comment: Quick question, what would that look like inside a function?

Comment: function fr($str) { return substr($str,0,3); }